# How to make a UIScrollView snap to icons (like App Store: Feature)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, uiscrollview

What I want to get is the same behaviour that this scroll view has:

[image: App Store feature scroll view (left)]

I know that this is using HTML and not the native API, but I'm trying to implement it as a UIKit component.

**Now, to the behaviour I'm looking for:**

- Notice that it's a paged scroll view, but the "page size" is less than the view's width.
- When you scroll it from left to right each page "snap" to the left-most item.
- When you scroll it from the right end to the left it "snaps" to the right-most item.

The same page but now right-to-left:

[image: App Store feature scroll view (right)]

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried making the scroll view smaller than it's super view and overriding hitTest, and that got me that left-to-right behaviour.
- I've tried implementing scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: and setting the targetContentOffset I want but since I can't change the velocity it just scrolls too slowly or too fast.
- I've tried implementing scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and then animating to the correct offset but the scroll view first stops then moves, it doesn't look natural.
- I've tried implementing scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: and then animating to the correct offset but the scroll view "jumps" and does not animate correctly.

I'm out of ideas.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I ended up using Rob Mayoff's method, it looks clean. 
I changed it so it would work when the velocity is 0, for example when a user drags, stops and releases the finger.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
              targetContentOffset:(CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    CGFloat maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat minOffset = 0;

    if (velocity.x == 0) {
        CGFloat targetX = MAX(minOffset,MIN(maxOffset, targetContentOffset->x));

        CGFloat diff = targetX - baseOffset;

        if (ABS(diff) > offsetStep/2) {
            if (diff > 0) {
                //going left
                baseOffset = MIN(maxOffset, baseOffset + offsetStep);
            } else {
                //going right
                baseOffset = MAX(minOffset, baseOffset - offsetStep);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (velocity.x > 0) {
            baseOffset = MIN(maxOffset, baseOffset + offsetStep);
        } else {
            baseOffset = MAX(minOffset, baseOffset - offsetStep);
        }
    }

    targetContentOffset->x = baseOffset;
}
```

The only problem with this solution is that swiping the scroll view doesn't produce the "bounce" effect. It feels "stuck".

Comment: Any chance that this could be achieved using a UITableView/UICollectionView? I want the same scroll and snap effect but with the table/collection to preview the next/previous items like the one in iTunes. Doing something like 4 rows in 1 column table/collection.

Comment: To everybody who wants to fix the "stuck" feel: If abs(velocity.x) is bigger than say 0.8, you can add / subtract two offsetSteps instead of one.

Comment: Don't forget the incredibly simple way to do this. (Particularly with autolayout.  JUST MAKE THE LITERAL SCROLL VIEW, **SIMPLY THE SIZE OF THE "UNIT"**.  And make it page. It's just that simple. Use super-ingenious [technique something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37505837/294884) if needed to adjust "touchable area"

Comment: Did you manage to do this? Any example using Storyboard?

Comment: @Fattie could you please elaborate?  I want something like the App Store.  But when I mimic the UI (with the next element partially visible on the right) and enable paging, it pages up to the next visible area.  That is, if first view is shown, and the second item is shown 10pt, it pages to 11th pt of the second item.

Comment: @SeopYoon surprisingly make the scrollView, actually only as wide as the size of one "unit".  (You will still see the rest, assuming you don't have clipping turned on.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting `scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`, combined with implementing `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`, seems to work for me using a collection view.

First, I give myself some instance variables:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSString *cellClassName;
    CGFloat baseOffset;
    CGFloat offsetStep;
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`, I set the view's `decelerationRate`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    cellClassName = NSStringFromClass([MyCell class]);
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:cellClassName bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellClassName];
    self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
}
```

I need `offsetStep` to be the size of an integral number of items that fit in the view's on-screen bounds.  I compute it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    CGFloat stepUnit = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing;
    offsetStep = stepUnit * floorf(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / stepUnit);
}
```

I need `baseOffset` to the be the X offset of the view before scrolling starts.  I initialize it in `viewDidAppear:`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    baseOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

Then I need to force the view to scroll in steps of `offsetStep`.  I do that in `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`.  Depending on the `velocity`, I increase or decrease `baseOffset` by `offsetStep`.  But I clamp `baseOffset` to a minimum of 0 and a maximum of the `contentSize.width - bounds.size.width`.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (velocity.x < 0) {
        baseOffset = MAX(0, baseOffset - offsetStep);
    } else if (velocity.x > 0) {
        baseOffset = MIN(scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width, baseOffset + offsetStep);
    }
    targetContentOffset->x = baseOffset;
}
```

Note that I don't care what `targetContentOffset->x` comes in as.

This has the effect of aligning to the left edge of the leftmost visible item, until the user scrolls all the way to the last item.  At that point it aligns to the right edge of the rightmost visible item, until the user scroll all the way to the left.  This seems to match the behavior of the App Store app.

If that doesn't work for you, you can try replacing the last line (`targetContentOffset->x = baseOffset`) with this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(baseOffset, 0) animated:YES];
    });
```

That also works for me.

You can find my test app [in this git repository](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-15961099-appStoreScrollView).

Answer (score 12):

You can either turn on `pagingEnabled`, or use `decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast` combined with `scrollViewDidEndDragging` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` (which will minimize the effect of slowing scrolling to one location and then animating again to another location). It's probably not precisely what you want, but it's pretty close. And by using `animateWithDuration` it avoids the instantaneous jumping of that final snap.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
        [self snapScrollView:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self snapScrollView:scrollView];
}
```

You can then write a `snapScrollView`, such as:

```
- (void)snapScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    if ((offset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width) >= scrollView.contentSize.width)
    {
        // no snap needed ... we're at the end of the scrollview
        return;
    }

    // calculate where you want it to snap to

    offset.x = floorf(offset.x / kIconOffset + 0.5) * kIconOffset;

    // now snap it to there

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                     animations:^{
                         scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution, works like App Store, with velocity or without it. `kCellBaseWidth` — width of cell.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    NSInteger index = lrint(targetContentOffset->x/kCellBaseWidth);
    targetContentOffset->x = index * kCellBaseWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Chiming in for Swift. [@avdyushin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243572/4848310)'s answer is by far the simplest and, as Ben mentioned, works very well. Although I did add a piece from [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15961379/4848310)'s answer regarding the end of the scrollview. Together, this solution seems to work perfectly.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width) >= scrollView.contentSize.width) {
        // no snap needed ... we're at the end of the scrollview
        return
    }

    let index: CGFloat = CGFloat(lrintf(Float(targetContentOffset.memory.x) / kCellBaseWidth))
    targetContentOffset.memory.x = index * kCellBaseWidth

}
```

Just add your `minimumLineSpacing` to `kCellBaseWidth`, and voila.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed to this. JUST A REMINDER: if you are using a 'minimumLineSpacing' in your FlowLayout then you must account for that value. Add it to kCellBaseWidth.

Comment: Wow, some amazing codes! For those with newer swift, targetContentOffset.memory.x  is now -> targetContentOffset.pointee.x