# ScrollView: is it possible to snap / paginate to elements inside?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, react-native

I'm looking for a way to build an interface similar to Apple App Store or iTunes where scrolling horizontally snaps to items inside. Essentially the way PagingEnabled snaps to the width of the ScrollView itself, but instead snapping to a smaller value I can set myself.

Here is a similar question where someone is looking to do this with straight ObjC: [How to make a UIScrollView snap to icons (like App Store: Feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961099/how-to-make-a-uiscrollview-snap-to-icons-like-app-store-feature)

Is this possible the way React Native's ScrollView is currently implemented? If not, any help pointing me in the right direction toward making my own component would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: There is a scrollView delegate method called 
- scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:.....This will give you a chance to adjust where the scrollView is allowed to stop scrolling....Changing the targetContentOffset (with the help of some Math) will do what you want.

Comment: rxb did you ever figure out how to do this within RN?