# IOS: Putting UICollectionViews into UIPageVieControllers

Tags: ios, swift, view, uicollectionview

In part of my app, I need to have a vertical scrolling apparatus to select levels (for which I'm currently using a collection view for). However I also need to allow the user to swipe left or right to present a new "floor" of levels. For instance there might be 50 levels in one floor and 4 floors. I like the gird-presentation of the collection view, I want the page control capabilities of a UIPageController.

I'm currently managing this (messily) with a blank view controller, into which I load a collection view. And a left swipe reloads this view controller and tells it to load a new collection view.

I don't like this, and I can't figure out how to mesh a collection view into a UIPageController. I think this is the best way to get what I want, but if there's a better approach, let me know.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `UIPageController`. I think you mean `UIPageViewController`.

Anyway, it sounds like you want something like the App Store's “Featured” tab. In the App Store, there's a top level collection view that only scrolls **vertically**. Each cell of this top level collection view represents a featured category and contains a (nested) collection view that only scrolls **horizontally** and contains one cell for each app in that featured category.

So, my advice is: don't use any `UIPageViewController`s. Do what the App Store does: use a top-level vertically-scrolling `UICollectionView`, with each cell containing its own nested horizontally-scrolling `UICollectionView`.

If you want paging behavior, either set `pagingEnabled` on each nested collection view (they have this property because `UICollectionView` subclasses `UIScrollView)`, or implement it “by hand” like the App Store does. I explained how to reproduce the App Store's customized horizontal stopping behavior in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15961871/77567).